# How can I show message boxes depending on a bool result?

Tags: c#, boolean

I currently have the following code in my Quit method:

```
public void QuitApplication(FormClosingEventArgs a, bool b)
{
    bool c = Properties.App.Default.AskToExit, d = Properties.App.Default.AskToSave;
    if (!b)
    {
        if (!c && !d)
        {

        }
        else if (!c)
        {
            if (YesNoMessageBox("Save Before Quit?", "Would you like to save your settings before you Quit?") == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                _debug("Settings Saved");

                //Properties.App.Default.Save();
                //Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
        else if (!d)
        {
            if (YesNoMessageBox("Really Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?") == DialogResult.No)
            {
                a.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (YesNoMessageBox("Really Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?") == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (YesNoMessageBox("Save Before Quit?", "Would you like to save your settings before you Quit?") == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    _debug("Settings Saved");

                    //Properties.App.Default.Save();
                    //Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                a.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is used to check if the user wants to quit and to save if they want to. However I have two options that can be set to ignore asking to save or asking to quit when they invoke this method. The only way to compare these I have thought of is the above and I'm sure you can do it so there's a lot less repetition. (The saving methods are commented out as the app is still in development and the settings files aren't done yet).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Asking so many things before quitting an application is really annoying

Comment: what should the if(!c && !d) do?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` really useful names? If I am a new developer looking at your code, what on earth is it supposed to mean?

Comment: and what @Habib said; this would be extremely annoying (and a mistake I once made myself)

Comment: They aren't really useful names no, but no one else will be taking this code on and I'm a little OCD.

C and D are the values of the specific settings options.

@habib yeah I know, that's why I've added options to remove them.

Comment: Are you going to remember what they mean, a few months down the line when you need to improve this?

Comment: just a suggestion, maybe you could check first IF there are any changes at all before all these questions are fired?

Comment: I have fixed this and hanged the names of my variables, I will start using proper names now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your parameter `b` does, please work on your variable naming. It seems like if it's true, it should skip all questions and quit anyway. It could then be named `forceQuit`.

This should do:

```
public void QuitApplication(FormClosingEventArgs closeArgs, bool forceQuit)
{
    if (forceQuit)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Properties.App.Default.AskToExit)
    {
        if (YesNoMessageBox("Really Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?") != DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // Cancel exit
            closeArgs.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (Properties.App.Default.AskToSave)
    {
        if (YesNoMessageBox("Save Before Quit?", "Would you like to save your settings before you Quit?") == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // Save
        }
    }
}
```

I'd say the second messagebox should be one with `Yes|No|Cancel`, where Cancel cancels the exit, or even better, don't use messageboxes at all.